# Trying to set org-clock-sound for org-timer

Tags: org-mode, doom, timers

I'm trying to set up a notification alert for org timer. I'm using Dunst on Arch for notifications.

Used the following lines in my config file:

```
(require 'org)
(setq org-clock-sound "~/Downloads/ding0.wav")
```

However, whenever I run `org-timer-set-timer`, it plays some weird white noise, instead of the file placed in the Downloads folder above.

How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: AFAICT, this is done by using `aplay`. So what happens if you run `aplay ~/Downloads/ding0.wav` from the bash command line?

Comment: Someone was watching David Wilson's video.

Comment: @NickD I ran `aplay ~/Downloads/ding0.wav ` and it played the same disturbing white noise sound.
When I opened the same file with vlc/mpv players, it played just fine.

Comment: @aadcg Haha! SystemCrafters REPRESENT!

Comment: So not an emacs or Org mode problem: an ALSA problem.

Comment: @NickD Any clues as to how I can resolve it ?

Comment: As I said, not an emacs or Org mode problem. Try asking why `aplay` does that perhaps on the [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). Also try `file ~/Downloads/ding0.wav` and see if it is indeed a WAV file: see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363176/ogg-auhttps://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363176/ogg-audio-file-and-aplay-white-noise. If it is not a WAV file, you might be able to convert it with something like `ffmpeg` - or get a real WAV file.

Comment: Lol you were right. I think I had just edited the "wav" extension into that file. Downloaded a proper "wav" file now and it works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
(setq org-clock-sound "~/class-is-over.mp3")
(defun my/play-sound (orgin-fn sound)
  (cl-destructuring-bind (_ _ file) sound
    (make-process :name (concat "play-sound-" file)
                  :connection-type 'pipe
                  :command `("afplay" ,file))))
(advice-add 'play-sound :around 'my/play-sound)
```

advice is your friend. afplay is available on macOS.

Comment: I am confused: what problem does this solve? AFAICT, the OP resolved the problem by using the correct file: no other change was needed. And why is the advice an `around` advice? It seems more that you are replacing a command. And `afplay` seems to be macOS-specific, so this has no chance of working on any other system, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the loop: the OP had downloaded a file and *thought* that it was a WAV file, but apparently it was not. OTOH, the Org clock timer uses `aplay` to play the sound and that can *only* play WAV files - nothing else. The OP downloaded a "real" WAV file and everything worked properly after that.